# Add an Image to Word Document and Scale it using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

how do i programatically add an image using VBA to a word document.

I've tried adding a bookmark to the word document and tried adding the image, but it always adds to the top of the form rather than the bookmark area. Should i persevere with the bookmark or is there another way to add the image?

See my code below:

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Dim objWdRange As Word.Range
Dim GraphImage As String
Dim shortString As String 

shortString = Range("short").Value

GraphImage = "http://xxx.xxxxx.com/xxx/xxx.png?instrument=Image.png"

wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Program Files\My Dropbox\dailystrategy.doc")

Set objWdRange = wrdDoc.Content

With wrdDoc


    If wrdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("shortString ") Then
        wrdDoc.Bookmarks("shortString ").Range.Text = shortString 
    End If      

     If wrdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("GraphImage") Then
        wrdDoc.Bookmarks("GraphImage").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:=GraphImage, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
     End If


    wrdDoc.SaveAs "c:\temp\test.doc"

  ' close the document
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
End With
```

regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first we need to clean up your code a bit, like below. This runs fine on my site - it places the image right at the front of the GraphicImage bookmark, not at the top of the document - but maybe your image is so large it extends to the top?

```
Dim objWdRange As Word.Range
Dim GraphImage As String
Dim shortString As String
shortString = Range("short").Value '? don't know what this is for
GraphImage = "http://xxx.xxxxx.com/xxx/xxx.png?instrument=Image.png"
wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Program Files\My Dropbox\dailystrategy.doc")
    Set objWdRange = wrdDoc.Content '? don't know what this is for
    With wrdDoc
        If .Bookmarks.Exists("shortString ") Then
           .Bookmarks("shortString ").Range.Text = shortString
        End If
     If .Bookmarks.Exists("GraphImage") Then
         Dim wrdPic As Word.InlineShape
         Set wrdPic = .Bookmarks("GraphImage").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=GraphImage, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
         wrdPic.ScaleHeight = 50
         wrdPic.ScaleWidth = 50
     End If
       .SaveAs "c:\temp\test.doc"
    End With
    wrdDoc.Close
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    wrdApp.Quit
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
```

---

EDIT: Jan 11, 2010
The above code was changed to include

```
 If .Bookmarks.Exists("GraphImage") Then
 Dim wrdPic As Word.InlineShape
 Set wrdPic = .Bookmarks("GraphImage").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=GraphImage, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    wrdPic.ScaleHeight = 50
    wrdPic.ScaleWidth = 50
 End If
```

This sets the picture as an object and then uses the scaling methods `ScaleHeight` and `ScaleWidth` to make it 50% smaller in both height and width.

Comment: hi, thanks for that, you are right, the image is being inserted in the right place, but it's dimensons are too big for the page. Is there anyway of setting the image dimensions programatically using VBA?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can use either the Height/Width properties of an Inline Shape, or you can use ScaleHeight/ScaleWidth as I've updated the code above with.