# Visual Basic Image Scaling

Tags: image, vba, vb6, scalability

Is it possible to scale an image proportionately in VB without one of the 3 or 4 built in properties (since they do not work so well)?

What I am referring to is something that you can do in Java like this:

```
Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(230, 310,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

In Java the above line seems to work nicely for scaling the dimensions to fit a specified size.

Comment: Your tags include VB.NET and VBA.  Are you looking for both?  Here is VBA implemention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029724/add-an-image-to-word-document-and-scale-it-using-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a UserControl that I used to accomplish a better quality resize.  Here is an extract from it, hopefully you can find it useful.

```
Private Const STRETCH_ANDSCANS = 1
Private Const STRETCH_DELETESCANS = 3
Private Const STRETCH_HALFTONE = 4
Private Const STRETCH_ORSCANS = 2
Private Const SRCCOPY = &HCC0020

Private Declare Function StretchBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal x As Long, _
                                                   ByVal y As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nWidth As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nHeight As Long, _
                                                   ByVal hSrcDC As Long, _
                                                   ByVal xSrc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal ySrc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nSrcWidth As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nSrcHeight As Long, _
                                                   ByVal dwRop As Long) _
                                                   As Long

Private Declare Function SetStretchBltMode Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
                                                      ByVal nStretchMode As Long) _
                                                      As Long
```

And it was called like this:

```
Private Sub UserControl_Paint()

   Dim lSave As Long

   'set the stretchblit mode (saving the previous value)
   lSave = SetStretchBltMode(UserControl.hdc, STRETCH_HALFTONE)

   'perform blit
   Call StretchBlt(UserControl.hdc, 0, 0, UserControl.ScaleWidth, _
                     UserControl.ScaleHeight, picBuffer.hdc, 0, 0, _
                     picBuffer.ScaleWidth, picBuffer.ScaleHeight, SRCCOPY)

   'restore previous mode
   Call SetStretchBltMode(UserControl.hdc, lSave)

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks pretty intense, I dont think my skills are quite to that level yet, but I will give it a go.  Thanks

Comment: Well, post back here if you have any follow-up questions on it.

Comment: Does "&HCC0020" mean 0xCC0020 ? Is this the value of SRCCOPY constant ? I'm not kidding I'm looking for constant values that aren't properly documented by Microsoft!

Comment: `&HCC0020` is VB syntax for a hexidecimal number.  It is the same as `0xCC0020` which is C/C++/C#/etc notation.