# How to insert an image to a word document using vba

Tags: vba

I have a word document, which contains such templates:

```
{{http://.../icon_1.png}}
... some arbitrary text
{{http://.../image_23.png}}
... etc.
```

What I want, is to replace `{{...}}` with corresponding images. To make the task simpler, let's suppose, that I have one and only one hardcoded tag `{{http://example.com/icon_1.png}}`.

**EDIT**

So, I got all my matches and can iterate through the document content like so:

```
For Each Match In oMatches
     With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
         .Text = Match.Value
         .Replacement.Text = "bar"
         .Wrap = wdFindContinue
         .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
     End With
Next
```

But in this test case, I just replace all matches with "bar" value, but what I want instead is to add a picture at each position (let it be some arbitrary hardcoded image).

Comment: Well, your first step should be the macro recording tool of office. Start, insert a picture, stop. That's how you get that bit. Then you have to insert that code snippet inside a loop that searches through the document on each position that holds your defined image templates.

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: @EngJon. I now able to loop through all matches. And I even able to replace all tags {{...}} with some value, but I'm still not sure how to replace it with an image.

Comment: Check this link out, I think it has your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029724/add-an-image-to-word-document-and-scale-it-using-vba

Comment: @PKatona. Unfrotunatelly, not. I do not have any bookmarks

Comment: I've seen many examples, where they use `Selection` variable and talk about 'insertion point'. I guess, If I knew how to move insertion point in my example, I could insert images with `Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\icon.png"`...

Comment: This one has examples without a bookmark. http://software-solutions-online.com/word-vba-insert-images/

Comment: Here's how to move the insertion point in the document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821348.aspx and 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822886.aspx

Comment: do the pictures always differ? are these links to the pictures in the brackets?