# VBA Excel Picture to Word Bookmark macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to amend a VBA macro to enable pasting of an Excel range (as a picture, for formatting purposes) to a Word bookmark.

```
Sub test2()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PREMIUMS")
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\TEST\BTM Macro Template.docx"

 With objWord.ActiveDocument
.Bookmarks("PLAN_1_SHEET").Range.Text = ws.Range("A34").Value
.Bookmarks("PLAN_2_SHEET").Range.Text = ws.Range("BTM_PREM").Value
End With
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

The macro pastes a single cell  text reference fine ("A34"), but using the same code for a range "BTM_PREM") returns a type mismatch error. 
I know it is due to the range not being a string, but can't seem to identify how to amend this line to enable pasting of "BTM_PREM", as a picture, at the "PLAN_2_SHEET" bookmark.

```
.Bookmarks("PLAN_2_SHEET").Range.Text = ws.Range("BTM_PREM").Value
```

Comment: Consider the advice given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029724/add-an-image-to-word-document-and-scale-it-using-vba

Comment: @Dave - thanks for the link. I did see this particular question, but had some difficulty developing the code to substitute the link to a graphic to one where the range is referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `Copy()` method on Excel `Range` object and then either [`Paste()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff845105.aspx) or [`PasteSpecial()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff821124.aspx) or [`PasteExcelTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193063.aspx) Word `Range` object methods, like follows:

```
ws.Range("BTM_PREM").Copy
.Bookmarks("PLAN_2_SHEET").Range.Paste
```

or

```
ws.Range("BTM_PREM").Copy
.Bookmarks("PLAN_2_SHEET").Range.PasteSpecial Link:=True
```

or

```
ws.Range("BTM_PREM").Copy
.Bookmarks("PLAN_2_SHEET").Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=True, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=True
```

Comment: Thanks for these options, as I was hoping a Paste Special object method would keep formatting intact. I've tried the above PasteSpecial option (copied as above), but get a Run-Time error "Method 'Range of Object' worksheet failed. Do I need to define the .ws further to address this?

Comment: For "ws.Range("BTM_PREM").Copy" statement to work you must have previously: 1) set "ws" to a valid worksheet (like "Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PREMIUMS")") 2) set a "BTM_PREM" named range in that worksheet (that you can do either in excel UI or via VBA code)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I now have the macro working, using the Range.Paste option as a test, and can paste the Excel info to the named bookmark. One last request - is there a line of code I can add such that the Excel range pastes into Word using the Keep Source Formatting paste option? This will ensure the Excel data does not extend past the boundaries of the Word document when pasted.

Comment: you're welcome. as to this site rules 1) if I answered your _original_ question, please mark the answer as accepted 2) for new issues you must make a new question, but first you may visit those three links I posted in my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is a piece of code that works for me:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Lease 1").Range("B16:AF25").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
wdoc.Bookmarks("Bkmrk1").Range.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

It's not a complete macro, just a part of it so you'll have to adjust a bit, But I think you get the idea.