# how to send image path in includepicture field using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have an access database which has a form. There is a submit button in this form. When I clicked this button, I'm running some vba codes. If all codes are running successfully, I'm creating ms word document with docvariables. So I want to send image path in includepicture field, to do this I wrote this codes

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE {DOCVARIABLE PICTURE}\* MERGEFORMAT}
```

I'm using this above code in my word document. These are my vba codes, I'm getting image path in my access database table.

```
  Dim imgPath As String
  Dim imgName As String
  Dim imgPath_rp As String
  Dim db_image As DAO.Database
  Dim rs_image As DAO.Recordset

    Set db_image = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\ftk1187\Desktop\Test WS_11-Jun-2018 - Copy.mdb", False, False, "")
    Set rs_image = db_image.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TableSıgnature WHERE ImageName = '" & Me.Combo474.Value & "'", dbOpenDynaset)


    If Me.Combo474.Value = rs_image!ImageName Then
        imgPath = rs_image!imagePath
    End If

    imgPath_rp = Replace(imgPath, "\", "\\")

  rs_image.Close
  Set rs_image = Nothing
  db_image.Close

  objDOC.Variables("PICTURE").Value = imgPath_rp
```

When I click submit button, it gives me no error but the image can't displayed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add an Image to Word Document and Scale it using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029724/add-an-image-to-word-document-and-scale-it-using-vba)

Comment: Or https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/16760-using-includepicture-mailmerge-insert-picture.html

Comment: @yokki I wrote something like this `objDOC.Range.Fields.Update`. All other fields updating but I still not display my image.

Comment: I wrote something like this  **{IF {INCLUDEPICTURE {IF TRUE "C:\\Users\\ftk1187\\Desktop\\signatures\\{DOCVARIABLE PICTURE}"} \d} {INCLUDEPICTURE {IF TRUE "C:\\Users\\ftk1187\\Desktop\\signatures\\{DOCVARIABLE PICTURE}"} \d}}** but it shows me nothing.

Comment: @June7 I tried your recommendations but they are not working for me. :(

Comment: @yokki I give up to do it using `INCLUDEPICTURE`. I'll do it like @June7 's first recommendation. Now it displays pictures but I having  problem positioning pictures.